# python for loop finishing before end of file

Tags: python

I'm parsing some text files (Cisco switch show version files) with the following script.  It works fine except it only picks up the 'serial number' & 'model' lines once, and there is more than one line with this info.  How can I get the script to keep going to parse the whole file?

```
import os
import csv

inventoryfile = open('inventory.csv', 'a')
write_inventory = csv.writer(inventoryfile)
#write_inventory.writerow( ('Hostname', 'Model', 'Serial Number') )

def parse_files(path):
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        with open(os.path.join(path,filename),'r') as showfile:
                for line in showfile:
#                   i = 0
#                   while i < 4:
                        if '#sh' in line:
                            hostname = line.split('#')[0]
                        if 'Model number' in line:
                            model = line.split()[-1]
                        if 'System serial number' in line:
                            serial = line.split()[-1]
                        elif 'Model Number' in line:
                            model = line.split()[-1]
                        elif 'System Serial Number' in line:
                            serial = line.split()[-1]
#                       i += 1
                write_inventory.writerow( (hostname, model, serial) )


directory = raw_input("Please specify Show Files directory: ")

parse_files(directory)
```

Comment: Your write_inventory line isn't inside the for loop, it will only run once per file.

Comment: @TonyBlundell if I put it inside the for loop I get this error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'hostname' referenced before assignment` which is why it's where it is.

Comment: That error's correct, you're accessing hostname but only assigning it if '#sh' is in the line.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand; 'accessing hostname but only assigning it if '#sh' is in the line'

Comment: So the write_inventory line uses the hostname variable - but if 'sh' isn't in the line, that hostname variable is never set. You need to set a variable before you can use it.

Comment: so if '#sh' or one of the other line identifiers is in the line then hostname/model/serial are assigned a value. But then If the line doesn't have the line identifier no value is set to the variables.  I still don't understand how this affects the write_inventory line.  I'm going to have to think on this a while, get my head around the logic.

Answer (score 2):

You are writing once per file instead of once per line, so it will only write last line. Place your write_inventory inside for loop

Comment: if I put it inside the for loop I get this error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'hostname' referenced before assignment` How would I have it inside the for loop without getting this error?

Comment: That is because it didn't have '#sh' in line, so you should initialize variable in every loop, or you could end up with different results than expected, like having hostname from previous line

Comment: ok, so, because of this `hostname = line.split('#')[0]` I'm not initialising the variable as if I was doing this: `hostname = foo`? How do I then assign the value from the line AND initialise the variable?  I'm new, obviously, and just trying to get my head round this.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know it's only picking up those lines once?  You only have one variable serial to store them in.  Each time it finds a relevant line it will overwrite that variable with the latest value.

If you want to record all instances of those lines you should save them in a list.

Comment: Ah, interesting, I hadn't checked but it's actually writing the last appearance of the line to file.  Thanks, I'll look at writing the results to a list.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not understand what they said,try this code:

```
import os
import csv

inventoryfile = open('inventory.csv', 'a')
write_inventory = csv.writer(inventoryfile)
#write_inventory.writerow( ('Hostname', 'Model', 'Serial Number') )

def parse_files(path):
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        with open(os.path.join(path,filename),'r') as showfile:
                for line in showfile:
#                   i = 0
#                   while i < 4:
                        hostname = model = serial = ''
                        if '#sh' in line:
                            hostname = line.split('#')[0]
                        if 'Model number' in line:
                            model = line.split()[-1]
                        if 'System serial number' in line:
                            serial = line.split()[-1]
                        elif 'Model Number' in line:
                            model = line.split()[-1]
                        elif 'System Serial Number' in line:
                            serial = line.split()[-1]
#                       i += 1
                        write_inventory.writerow( (hostname, model, serial) )


directory = raw_input("Please specify Show Files directory: ")

parse_files(directory)
```

Comment: this writes a load of commas to the file?

Comment: I mean you should define the variables first.If you do not want to write the commas,just skip them.  I think if you paste some contents of your files,others will know what code you need indeed.